# Firebase Bearer Token

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, unity-editor

I'm now working on RestAPI calls from Unity Editor to Firebase Cloud Messaging and Firebase Realtime Database. Here the code what I'm using to create a token with multiply scores.

```
private static readonly string[] _scores = new[]
        {
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging"
        };

public string CreateToken(DateTimeOffset now, string[] scores)
        {
            var nowSeconds = now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();
            var inOneHour = GetExpirationTime(now);

            var scope = string.Join(",", scores);

            var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "iss", _serviceAccountData.ClientEmail },
                { "scope", scope },
                { "aud", _serviceAccountData.TokenUri },
                { "iat", nowSeconds },
                { "exp", inOneHour }
            };

            return SignToken(payload);
        }
```

But this not working, calls to `https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{0}/messages:send` returns **401 Unauthorized**. If I'm passing only `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging` as scope everything working. But I still need to call firebase realtime database. Is that possible to use same **Bearer Token** to call both APIs or I need to have 2 different tokens for such a behavior?

I have "firebase_admin_sdk.json" in project and [Jose.JWT](https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt) to sign request.

Comment: My guess would be 2 different host names would mean 2 different tokens.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this also, but for me it's a little bit strange because OAuth server responds we with valid token.

Comment: Well it is. For www.googleapis….. not for fcm.google….. perhaps

Comment: I made separate module for Realtime Database and create token as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#node.js) (but with using Jose-jwt for signing) but still error 401. I provide data from `firebase_admin_sdk.json` as before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with removing comma from scopes and splitting tokens for messaging and realtime database.